# Simple R functions not working on new laptop with win 11

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to load raster files then mask out the clouded parts. I have done it many times and the code used to work fine. Now I upgraded to windows 11 and has a new laptop. Installed R 4.2, then RStudio and then RTools 4.2. Here is my code

```
`library(raster)
library(rgdal)

setwd('D:/Test/')

masks <- list.files('D:/Test', 'mask_C2.tif$', full.names = T)
ndvi <- list.files('D:/Test', 'NDVI_C2.tif$', full.names = T)
rm <- lapply(masks, raster)
rn <- lapply(ndvi, raster)

When I call 1st element on NEW MACHINE, 'names' property doesn't have file name, it just says layer
> rn[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 174, 164, 28536  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 323895, 328815, 3724335, 3729555  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : cr_LC81500372020261LGN00_NDVI_C2.tif 
names      : layer 
values     : -0.1510984, 0.8510309  (min, max)

When I call 1st element on OLD MACHINE, 'names' property has file name
> rn[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 174, 164, 28536  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 323895, 328815, 3724335, 3729555  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : cr_LC81500372020261LGN00_NDVI_C2.tif 
names      : cr_LC81500372020261LGN00_NDVI_C2
values     : -0.1510984, 0.8510309  (min, max)`
```

I was using names property to name output rasters which I'm unable to do now. I know basename can do this but really wanna know whats wrong here. same code works fine on old machine with same versions of R, RStudio and RTools.

Really appreciate if someone can help me here. Thanks

I reinstalled windows, did a clean install. Then installed same versions of R, Rstudio and RTools as my old computer has. As names property has file name on old computer, I want it to be same on new one.

Comment: You should look at the result of `sessionInfo()` on each machine after running the same code (and nothing else).  I expect versions of some packages are different.

Comment: Some general advice:  don't use the variable `T`, use the constant `TRUE`.  `T` can take any value, it's not always `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this on both machines and I'll make sure to use full expression TRUE

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, issue solved by installing older versions of raster and sp packages. I couldn't install older version of rgdal though. But it worked. I think there should be something in newer versions. As I'm using names property to sort, extract dates etc in my work flow. That's why I'm so concerned. Otherwise I'll have to rewrite whole code and insert names manually at every step.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those packages, but I'd guess there's a new way to get the same information if the information was reliable.  For example, maybe `names(rn[[1]])` would give you what you want.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. All layers get same name like QA_PIXEL or ndvi